# Highslide: how to add an overlay behind the gallery, to dim all page content?

Tags: javascript, overlays, highslide

I'd like to have all page content covered by a transparent overlay when opening an Highslide gallery. You can see what I mean if you go here http://www.csdalbenga.it and click on "Ci presentiamo in video". A modal window opens and an overlay is added between the window and the underlying content, which becomes less visible.

Is there a way to do this with Highslide's already existing functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard Highslide JS option. See http://highslide.com/examples/mini-gallery.html. Note the hs.dimmingOpacity setting.

(Just use highslide-full.js or highslide-full.min.js, instead of messing around with the various subsets of the script, like highslide-with-gallery.js The full script is smaller than even a single image, loads quickly, and contains all of the functionality you might want to use.)

Comment: Not a moron! Sometimes it's tough to find the features in a package if you don't guess the right search words to use. Once someone else points you in the right direction, you're good to go.